# Irregular animations from UITableView's deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview, ios7

**Summary**:
In editing mode, I'm deleting rows in a table view using a custom editing control, rather than the default red minus sign and delete confirmation button. Tick a row or multiple rows, then tap the Delete button in the tool bar. It's similar to the behavior seen in the Mail app. See the screenshot below.

[image]

**Problem**:
The animations produced by calls to `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` are irregular. For example, here's what happens when I use the Bottom row animation (i.e., `UITableViewRowAnimationBottom`) to delete the ticked row (Subject #7) in the screenshot:

1. Subject #8 slides underneath and behind Subject #7
2. Subject #8 is briefly hidden behind Subject #7
3. Subject #8 replaces Subject #7 jarringly

This is occurring on both the simulator and on a device. The Automatic animation type (i.e., `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic`) produces the same irregular behavior when deleting Subject #7 above.

The Top animation type works as expected in the simulator but produces inconsistent, jarring animations on a device.

The Fade type animation is the only animation that works as expected in both the simulator and on a device.

**Details**:

I'm targeting iOS 7, and using storyboard, pure auto layout, and Core Data.

Here's the action method where I delete the rows:

```
- (void)deleteButtonTapped:(UIBarButton *)sender
{
    // update table view's data
    [self.listOfItems removeObjectsAtIndexes:self.indexSetOfTickedRows];

    // create index paths for ticked rows
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self.indexSetOfTickedRows enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]];
    }];

    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

    // update Core Data and UI...
}
```

**What I have tried:**

The table cell subclass overrides `layoutSubviews`. However, the irregular animations persist even when I comment out `layoutSubviews`.

I also removed the custom tickable editing control from the table cells, then hard-coded the deletion of a specific row in the action method. The irregular animations persisted.

As suggested by others, I've tried calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` between calls to `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. This does not resolve the issue.

Any suggestions on what to do next, or best guesses as to why I am seeing these irregular animations?

**Update (iOS 7.1):**

Issue remains after targeting iOS 7.1. Will continue to rely on fade animation.

Comment: I'm having similar issues, I'm getting strange animations where the separator line moves in one direction and the cell content another. Again I'm using pure auto-layout and iOS7. Seems buggy to me.

Comment: I've seen this sort of behavior when threading is not done properly. That would be the first place I'd look.

Comment: Don't you need calls to `begin` and `end` updates?

Comment: I have same problem any solutions?

Comment: Wow, that is a beautiful interface you have there @bilo.. I know this is off topic, but could you please share some resources on how you were able to do the following: 1) have a lovely black tick icon, preferably an image source or something; 2) how you were able to have your edit selection option on the right of each cell to have a nice line showing beside it on the left of it? And, 3) how you created that nice bar at the bottom with that text that i assume updates itself each time you select another cell, is that with a tool bar and a didSelect delegate method? Perhaps you could email me

Comment: I tried reloading the index path of the table view and adjusting the table view height to 0.0f but still face with irregularity, the alpha option seems like a good idea but I haven't get around to try it.

Its quite frustrating that we can't do table view animation like mail or other apple app where their animation seems to be flawless.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling 
`[self.listOfItems removeObjectsAtIndexes:self.indexSetOfTickedRows];`
at the end of the function instead of at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[tableView beginUpdates];` and `[tableView endUpdates];`

Comment: Doesn't resolve the issue. I've concluded that it's a bug. For now, I'm using the fade animation, which behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting the alpha on the cell works as suggested here. Not sure though.
[problems with animation when deleting the last row of a TableView in ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976700/problems-with-animation-when-deleting-the-last-row-of-tableview-ios7)

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I didn't see any mention of alpha in the post you referred to.

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant to refer to the updated link above. It worked for me a bit in a way the the cell about to be deleted gets hidden. This improved the animation for me because otherwise it was looking bit weird as i had cells with different heights. But apparently setting the alpha didn't work well in iOS6. so i resorted to set the 'hidden' property to 'YES'.