# deleteRowsAtIndexPaths Overlap Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

Trying to be ios7-esque, I am inserting a UIPickerView into a UITableView when tapping on a cell in the table. This works fine and animates nicely.  However, there is an issue when I retract the cell by calling deleteRowsAtIndexPaths.

I am experiencing a "bleed"/overlap where the picker is hiding one of the cells further down in the table view. See the screenshots.

I'm not doing anything super custom, so I wonder if this is an iOS7 bug.  All cells have solid background colors (white).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Tapping the top row**
[image: This is what it looks like after tapping the top row to reveal the picker]

**This is mid animation when retracting. Notice the overlap and the picker bleeding out over the cell at the bottom**
[image: Strange overlap]

Comment: When the animation is over, are all the table cells as they should be? Is the issue with just the animation itself?

Comment: Also, which animation type are you passing to deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:, e.g., automatic, bottom, top, etc.?

Comment: When the animation has completed, everything is fine and the UI looks as it should.

I have tried all animation types and they all yield the same result.

Comment: I have also noticed irregular animations from calling deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:. I posted a question about the issue here:http://stackoverflow.com/q/19474665/1239263 The question attracted so little attention that I earned the Tumbleweed badge for it. I still don't have a solution.

Comment: I'd be interested to see what this view looks like with some UIColor redColor/greenColor/etc on the backgroundViews...specifically of your Choose Product cell.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why, but it looks to me like the picker cell is covering the cell below "Choose Product". If this is indeed the case, one workaround would be to explicitly set the z-order of your cells, placing the picker cell under all others:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = ...;// your logic for getting a cell
    BOOL isPickerCell = ...;// your logic for identifying if this is the picker cell
    cell.layer.zPosition = isPickerCell ? 0 : 1;
}
```

If the picker is near the bottom of the table, it could still show through below the last cell since there's nothing there to cover it. For example, if "Choose Product" were the last cell. You can work around this by inserting blank cell(s) at the bottom. This is a general problem with having cells of varying height.

Comment: Same problem I am using default cell of a height with custom header view.DeleteRow/Section animation is really bad

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this problem, I realised that Apple's calendar application has the same issue

[image]

However, they minimise the side effects by inserting the row with a `.fade` animation.

```
tableView.insertRows(at: indexes, with: .fade)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues (iOS 8, iPhone 6 simulator)

In my case, I had a custom cell containing a `DatePicker` being inserted/deleted either between `Right Detail` style cells or between a `Right Detail` style cell and the section footer, which worked **as expected**.

```
[self.table beginUpdates];

if (isVisible) {
    [self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
} else {
    [self.table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
}

[self.table endUpdates];
```

But I also had `Right Detail` style cell being inserted/deleted between a `Right Detail` style cell and the end of section, which did not work as expected using the same code. The appearing/disappearing cell was visible on top of/through the cell above, and the cell moved twice as far as it should have. In the image below, People is appearing below Privacy, mid-animation.

[image]

However, I noticed that when the beginUpdates/endUpdates were commented out, the cell only moved about half a cell height instead of twice a cell height which meant that it looked much improved.

I also tried setting the zPosition which appeared to lessen the visibility when the cells overlapped.

```
// [self.table beginUpdates];

if (isVisible) {
    [self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
} else {
    cell = [self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:peopleIndex];
    cell.layer.zPosition = -1;
    [self.table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[peopleIndex]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
}

// [self.table endUpdates];
```

[image]